invalid transaction: Transaction failed to sanitize accounts offsets correctly
Hope someone can help? We are integrating solana into our interoperable web2/web3 platform called the oasis and having issues minting an nft, we are getting this error: "invalid transaction: Transaction failed to sanitize accounts offsets correctly".
Upon research I found this: "SanitizeFailure
Transaction failed to sanitize accounts offsets correctly implies that account locks are not taken for this TX, and should not be unlocked."
Which we found here: https://docs.rs/solana-sdk/latest/solana_sdk/transaction/enum.TransactionError.html
So looks like you need to lock the accounts or something? But not sure how to do that? Any tips of guidance or where to look would be appreciated thanks :) ❤️ We are using c#.

did you find an answer? Im running into it
